# How to change background color of a reusable component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, components, styling, code-reuse

I have a CTA component in React project.  I am using it a few times on my page.  I would like to change the background color and color of the text for one of the CTA uses.  How can I do that?

I tried to add a className to one of the CTA components and style it but nothing changed. I also trying to add an inline style.
My App.js file has the CTA component:

```
<CTA  word='CTA HERE' className='unique-cta-styling' style={{color: 'black'}}/>
```

My CTA component is this:

```
import '../../style/CTA.scss'

const CTA = ({ ...props }) => {
    return (
        <div
            class='CTA' 
            onClick={props.onClick}
        >
            {props.word}
        </div>
    )
}

export default CTA
```

Comment: What's inside this CTA component ? Where is this ClassName being passed ?

Comment: Just updated the question with my CTA component.

Comment: I have also found this which I thought was an interesting solve except how do I apply this solution to just a simple background color change for a CTA?  https://itnext.io/writing-customizable-styled-react-components-51d38ed20461

Answer (score 1):

`className='unique-cta-styling'` only applies, a priori to HTML tags. React components may or may not do anything with `className` props.

To style a React component, you could wrap it inside a `<div>` that you control.

```html
<div className='cta-styling' style={{background-color: 'black'}}>
  <CTA  word='CTA HERE' />
</div>
```

Here you can also style html elements rendered by the CTA component. For example, to style `<span>` elements that the CTA component renders, you could add the following to your CSS file:

```css
.cta-styling span {
  color: 'red';
}
```

---

Edit: since you can edit your component you can pass your props to the child.

```
const CTA = ({word, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <div {...props}>
           {word}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't want to add another div to the DOM.  And it doesn't actually change the color of the component itself.  I just want to be able to dynamically change the background color and text color of my existing component without creating a new div.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `Styled Components`. Which can be read about [here](https://www.styled-components.com/). They also have a nice button example which you can read about.

```
import React from 'react';

import StyledCTA from '../../style/styled-CTA';

const CTA = ({
  onClick,
  word,
  backgroundColor,
  textColor,
}) => (
  <StyledCTA
    onClick={onClick}
    backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
    textColor={textColor}
  >
    {word}
  </StyledCTA>
);

export default CTA;
```

And then in your styled component file you can have the following:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const getBackgroundColor = ({ backgroundColor }) => backgroundColor || 'red';
const getTextColor = ({ textColor }) => textColor || 'black';

export default styled.button`
  // Other static styling goes here
  background-color: ${getBackgroundColor};
  color: ${getTextColor};
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. You can see it running at this link[
https://jsfiddle.net/wu7kv15q/1/] too.

The main catch in your code was that, you have to explicitly map the ClassName till the html elements in case of custom components.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
         <CTA  word='CTA HERE' className='unique-cta-styling' style={{color: 'red'}}/>
    )
  }
}

    const CTA = ({ word,className,style,onClick }) => {
        return (
            <div
                className={`CTA ${className}`} 
                onClick={onClick}
                style={style}

            >
                {word}
            </div>
        )
    }

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wu7kv15q/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/)

Using styled components you can do something like following.
you can style this component in a js file (styles.js):

```
export const YourComponent= styled.button`
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: ${props => {
           switch (props.yourProps) {
                 case "Status01":
                     return "#0D47A1";
                 case "Status02":
                     return "#2E7D32";
                 default:
                      return "#FF8F00";
         }
        }};

       &:hover {
          background-color: ${props => {
              switch (props.yourProps) {
                 case "Status01":
                     return "#0D47A1";
                 case "Status02":
                     return "#2E7D32";
                 default:
                      return "#FF8F00";
         }
        }};
       }
```

`;

and import it in your component file.

```
 import { YourComponent } from './styles'
 <YourComponent
   yourProps="Status01"
 >
     Component Name
 </YourComponent>
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Ah interesting. I have used styled components before but not with a switch case inside of it.